# A date column in Google Sheets, e.g column B, that fills itself when I enter a value to its neighbour cell in column A

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I need to create a date column that automatically returns the date in which I filled its neighbour cell. For example, when I enter data to cell `A2`, `B2` will return the date the data was entered to `A2`.

Comment: =If(A2="","",A2) write this formula in B2 and drag it

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from @[JPV](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/83521/jpv)'s [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74320/60716):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    watchCols = [1],
    offsetCol = [1],
    ind = watchCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
    if (s.getName() !== "Sheet1" || ind === -1) return;
e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind])
    .setValue(!e.value ? null : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy.MM.dd"))
}
```

Date in 'scientific' format and based around GMT. Only applies to `Sheet1`.

Copy code into Tools > Script editor..., Save it (Ctrl+S), Run it (►) and give it permission.