# Multiple timestamps in multiple columns on multiple Google Sheet tabs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I am trying to work out what script is required to have multiple timestamps on several tabs however each one I have tried doesn't work for me.  I am new to this.

When text is added to column 2 I need a timestamp in column 1.  When text added in 8 I need a timestamp in 7.  When 15 which is a checkbox, a timestamp in 16, and when 18, timestamp in 17.  Is this possible to have so many?

My current script is as follows and this is giving me the time stamp in column 1 when column 2 is amended and it doesnt overwrite when it is changed a second time.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if (col === 2 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "June 2021") {
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).getValue() == "") {
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details including what you tried and a brief but specific description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi Ruben I have added my current script.  I have searched the other similar questions on this site and tried different scripts of tweaking this but i cannot make anything work?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Sophie: It's recommended to include links to at least one of the posts that have been reviewed. Anyway, I think that you should spend some time learning the JavaScript basics in order to be able to better adapt the scripts that you might find on the web to your specific cases. 

An `onEdit` simple trigger is ran when any range from bounded spreadsheet edited. You might control when a change is made over the spreadsheet by using JavaScript statements with *expressions*. The `if` statement is one of the most commonly used but it also could be done with other statements like `switch`.

Comment: [Related 1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74314/88163), [Related 2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154011/88163)

Answer (score 0):

A single `onEdit(e)` function can watch multiple columns on multiple sheets and insert timestamps in multiple columns depending on which column was edited and what the new value in the cell is. See the [timestampMultipleColumns_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28719648?msgid=28825318) script for an example.